# NSMutableDictionary not being set properly

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I suspect I'm missing something obvious here, but this is not working as it should be..

```
treeRects = @[@83,@18,@227.5,@0,@6.5,@136.45,@268,@62.45,@36,@239.45,@268,@194.45];

    [collisionRects setObject:treeRects forKey:@"Tree1"];
```

and the reason that's not working is because collisionRects is not initialised, but I can't seem to get it to do that, everytime I type something like

collisionRects = [collisionRects alloc] it actually comes up with the AllKeys option, not alloc. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to initialize an NSMutableDictionary is as follows:

```
collisionRects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

of if you know roughly the size you will need:

```
collisionRects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
```

Comment: Ok but do I need to initialize it? shouldn't the setObject work anyway? Because after the SetObject instruction collisionRects still = nil.

Comment: `-dictionary` is an initializer. So you're initializing `collisionRects` there.